# Ruby: Large data RSA Encryption

Tags: java, ruby, rsa, encryption-asymmetric

so I need to encrypt strings using RSA.

The example of the string (this is verified correct string):

```
"1658135277&{\"user_id\":\"f257bf74-8c14-4144-aca5-69e1d8819d9d\",\"user_id_type\":\"3\",\"user_name\":\"{\\\"first_name\\\":\\\"SEAN\\\",\\\"middle_name\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"last_name\\\":\\\"YEO\\\",\\\"full_name\\\":\\\"SEAN YEO\\\"}\",\"user_dob\":\"1993-03-31\",\"nationality\":\"SG\",\"user_address\":\"{\\\"region\\\":\\\"SG\\\",\\\"address_line1\\\":\\\"200 Jalan Sultan, 03-02, Textile Centre\\\"}\"}"
```

The ruby code:

```rb
def get_base64_encryption(unix_timestamp, params)
  str = "#{unix_timestamp}&#{params.to_json}"
  public_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(PUBLIC_KEY_PEM)
  encrypted_str = public_key.public_encrypted(str, OpenSSL::PKey::RSA::PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING)

  Base64.strict_encode64(encrypted_str)
end
```

But this way, it will raise error `OpenSSL::PKey::RSAError (data too large for key size)`

The thing is, I need to encrypt this for integration with 3rd party API. So there's no way I can use other encryption.

The partner actually gave example code, but in java:

```java
public class RSAUtil {

    private static final String KEY_ALGORITHM = "RSA";
    private static final String RSA_ALGORITHM = "RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-1AndMGF1Padding";

    // rsa secret key length 256 bytes（2048bit）
    private static final int MAX_DECRYPT_BLOCK = 256;

    // rsa encrypt data length
    private static final int MAX_ENCRYPT_BLOCK = 200;

    /**
     * rsa encrypt data
     * @param message
     * @param publicKeyStr
     * @return
     */
    public static String rsaEncryptOAEP(String message, String publicKeyStr) {
        try {
            System.out.println("message_size:" + message.length());
            Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
            byte[] publicKeyStrByte = decoder.decode(publicKeyStr);
            X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKeyStrByte);
            KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM);
            PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(RSA_ALGORITHM);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
            byte[] inputData = message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            int inputLen = inputData.length;

            byte[] cache = null;
            byte[] out = null;
            // split data by block size
            for (int offSet = 0; offSet < inputLen; offSet += MAX_ENCRYPT_BLOCK) {
                if (offSet + MAX_ENCRYPT_BLOCK < inputLen) {
                    cache = cipher.doFinal(inputData, offSet, MAX_ENCRYPT_BLOCK);
                } else {
                    cache = cipher.doFinal(inputData, offSet, inputLen - offSet);
                }
                out = mergeBytes(out, cache);
            }
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(out);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            System.out.println("current java env not support RSA v1.5/OAEP");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            System.out.println("invalid key");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e) {
            System.out.println("block size more than 214 ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }

    /**
     * merge 2 bytes
     *
     * @param first
     * @param last
     * @return
     */
    private static byte[] mergeBytes(byte[] first, byte[] last) {
        if (first == null) {
            return last;
        }
        byte[] result = new byte[first.length + last.length];
        System.arraycopy(first, 0, result, 0, first.length);
        System.arraycopy(last, 0, result, first.length, last.length);
        return result;
    }
}
```

But I still failed to translate the example code to ruby, especially because I couldn't find how to encrypt data in streaming fashion using RSA in ruby. Anyone can help? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who comes up with this problem, here is the answer:

```rb
def get_base64_encryption(unix_timestamp, params)
  str = "#{unix_timestamp}&#{params.to_json}"

  public_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(PUBLIC_KEY_PEM)
  encrypted_str = ''
      
  io = StringIO.new(str)
  until io.eof?
    chunk = io.read(200)
    encrypted_str << public_key.public_encrypt(chunk, OpenSSL::PKey::RSA::PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING)
  end

  Base64.strict_encode64(encrypted_str)
end
```

`OpenSSL::PKey::RSA::PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING` is equal to `RSA/ECB/OAEPWITHSHA-1ANDMGF1PADDING` [source](https://docs.helix.q2.com/docs/programpublickeyalgorithms)